# POST request Server returned HTTP response code: 500 /JAVA

Tags: java, http-post

I've being trying to send a POST request in JAVA, to a service that I'm running locally. When I make the request on POSTMAN as shown below I get a 200 response along with the JSON data response that I'm looking for

**Postman Example**
[image]

**Postman Response!**

```
[
  {
    "id": "Period10",
    "text": "In 10 years",
    "uniqueId": "946bf224-9031-402e-9753-b665be491acd",
    "extendedResults": {
      "/InsuredAgeMin$value": 0,
      "_order": 0,
      "/InsuredAgeMin/InsuredAgeMax$value": 45,
      "/InsuredAgeMin$id": 0,
      "/InsuredAgeMin/InsuredAgeMax/Term$id": "Period10",
      "name": "/InsuredAgeMin/InsuredAgeMax/Term",
      "/InsuredAgeMin/InsuredAgeMax$id": 45,
      "ref-data-id": "M_282_LSWL.Config.PaymentTerm.2",
      "locale": "en-jp",
      "/InsuredAgeMin/InsuredAgeMax/Term$value": "In 10 years"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "Period11",
    "text": "In 11 years",
    "uniqueId": "73608932-03b9-4cb6-8cb4-84e01bccb44c",
    "extendedResults": {
      "/InsuredAgeMin$value": 0,
      "_order": 1,
      "/InsuredAgeMin/InsuredAgeMax$value": 45,
      "/InsuredAgeMin$id": 0,
      "/InsuredAgeMin/InsuredAgeMax/Term$id": "Period11",
      "name": "/InsuredAgeMin/InsuredAgeMax/Term",
      "/InsuredAgeMin/InsuredAgeMax$id": 45,
      "ref-data-id": "M_282_LSWL.Config.PaymentTerm.2",
      "locale": "en-jp",
      "/InsuredAgeMin/InsuredAgeMax/Term$value": "In 11 years"
    }
  },
```

But when I try to do the same thing using JAVA I have been unsuccessful. This is the code I've been using.

**Java Code**

```
private static JSONObject JSONPostResponse() throws IOException, JSONException {
        String query = "http://localhost:8081/harmony/api/service/referenceData/M_282_LSWL.Config.PaymentTerm.2";
        String json = "{\"ref-data-id\":\"M_282_LSWL.Config.PaymentTerm.2\",\"filter./InsuredAgeMin$id\":{\"value\":30,\"operator\":\"lte\"},\"filter./InsuredAgeMin/InsuredAgeMax$id\":{\"value\":30,\"operator\":\"gte\"},\"name\":{\"value\":\"/InsuredAgeMin/InsuredAgeMax/Term\",\"operator\":\"equal\"},\"locale\":\"en-jp\",\"_sort\":{\"_order\":\"asc\"}}";


        CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
        URL url = new URL(query);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("cache-control", "no-cache");
        conn.setRequestProperty("postman-token", "5b70f93d-7358-eeb3-0581-9ec8f46d7b0e");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);


        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        os.close();

        // read the response
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        String result = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);


        in.close();
        conn.disconnect();

        return jsonObject;
    }
```

The above code gives me the error below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://methmy-qa2-r2.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/harmony/api/service/referenceData/LSWL.MainCoverage.PaymentTerm
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1676)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1672)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1245)
    at com.metlife.harmony.selenium.utils.JSONObjectReader.sendPost(JSONObjectReader.java:158)
    at com.metlife.harmony.selenium.utils.JSONObjectReader.main(JSONObjectReader.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://methmy-qa2-r2.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/harmony/api/service/referenceData/LSWL.MainCoverage.PaymentTerm
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1627)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at com.metlife.harmony.selenium.utils.JSONObjectReader.sendPost(JSONObjectReader.java:153)
```

I actually am not too sure what I've to do from here, am I doing the body request wrong, should I create java pojos?

Am I missing out something in the request to the localhost? that's essential for the request to happen?

I'm not too sure and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards, Nikos.

Comment: server returns 500 -> means something is wrong on the server -> ask the server what is wrong.

Comment: How come when I do the post with Postman it works and the java code gives out 500?

Comment: could be any number of things that your server does not like. Only the server knows what specific difference in the configuration caused to problem

Comment: What's the best way to figure that out? through the apache logs? This is mind bungling me, like why on gods name is it that hard to send a post body request?